# get node_exporter metrics for a single system user

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have installed the node_exporter within the userspace of a linux system user. Everything works and I get the metrics in my grafana. But what I get is apperently the metrics for the whole host system (interesting, that I can get so much data about the host system as a simple user). But what I want is to see the CPU usage or RAM usage etc. just for my user, is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK, node_exporter itself doesn't provide such functionality, and it would be particularly misleading for memory due to buffers, shares and such. But if youare sure that you really need this, you can utilise textile collectors of node_exporter, and write a script that will be preparing needed data. Good starting point for this might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194733/21363224

Answer (score 0):

What datasource are you using?
How do you transfer data from your collector (node_exporter) to grafana?

You could use a combination of telegraf agents and influxdb to create tags (eg users) and then filter your metrics based on those tags.